Change the title "Gallery" in Buddypress/MediaPress to "Videos & Audio"
The default heading in the menu for the photos in Buddypress is "Gallery". I'm using the MediaPress to upload Video and Audio also. I'd like "Gallery" to say "Videos & Audio". Here's a link to the image:
Image of Gallery title
function rename_mediapress_profile_tab() {
    $name = sprintf(__(‘Videos & Audio <span>%d</span>’, ‘mediapress’), mpp_get_total_gallery_for_user());
    buddypress()->members->nav->edit_nav( array( ‘name’ => __( $name, ‘mediapress’ ) ), ‘videos & audio’ );
    }
    add_action( ‘bp_actions’, ‘rename_mediapress_profile_tab’ );


It appears that the issue lies with the following line:
buddypress()->members->nav->edit_nav( array( 'name' => __( $name, 'mediapress' ) ), 'videos & audio' );

$name is already a dynamic, formatted string that includes content translated through sprintf(__('...', 'mediapress'), ...).
Additionally, the slug should be 'mediapress' instead of 'videos & audio'.
Here is the corrected code:
function rename_mediapress_profile_tab() {
    // Define the new tab name with the total count of galleries
    $name = sprintf(__('Videos & Audio <span>%d</span>', 'mediapress'), mpp_get_total_gallery_for_user());
    
    // Edit the nav tab for MediaPress (replace 'mediapress' with the actual slug if it's different)
    buddypress()->members->nav->edit_nav(array('name' => $name), 'mediapress');
}
add_action('bp_actions', 'rename_mediapress_profile_tab');


Thanks but unfortunately doesn't work. Nothing changed, still says Gallery.

The key in BuddyPress is 'mediapress' instead of 'gallery'. The correct code is:
buddypress()->members->nav->edit_nav(array('name' => $name), 'mediapress');
Actual applied result:
https://wpdev.wantnote.com/members/wgsxzg/

Works perfectly - thank you!

Congratulations! I have edited my initial post to ensure that, just in case anyone with the same question misses the comments, they can still see the updated response.
